# web service link

Tags: asp.net

How to change the web service link in a asp.net project?

Comment: How did you create it in the first place? Using VS.NET?

Comment: i did not create it. I need to change it in a .dll file but i cant since it is locked.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can elaborate your issue. The web service call is implemented inside the DLL which you do not have access to it's source codes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm clutching at straws here but is the URL stored in the configuration file? Or you could use reflector (http://reflector.red-gate.com/) to obtain the source code for the class and then reimplement the web service however you need to.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the web service reference
click on configure service reference

the link is in the address bar of the next window.

failing that you shold look in the web.config file ...

there is a section called client (inside system.serviceModel) probably towards the end ... modify the address in there and away you go good sir!

If this file does not exist then you may even have to create it as unless the developer decided to totally implement the service reference himself and *handcoded* all of the code required to generate the service and its references and corresponding classes (highly unlikley) then you will need reflector. I find this last scenario highly unlikley though.

an example of the section

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWCFCOPService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1364/WCFCOPService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWCFCOPService" contract="COPWCFService.IWCFCOPService" name="WSHttpBinding_IWCFCOPService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```